# Limit column text length in elasticsearch response

Tags: elasticsearch, search, substring

Following is my elasticsearch mapping

```
{
  "metadata" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties": {
        "id": {"type":"keyword"},
        "title": {"type":"keyword"},
        "created": {"type":"date"},
        "modified": {"type":"date"},
        "keyword": {"type":"keyword"},
        "description": {"type":"text"}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my ES query to retreive data based on user query on multiple fields, limit to top 5 hits, sort by modified date and display only title & description fields. The query works perfectly as I expect.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "UK House Price Index",
            "fields" : ["title", "keyword", "description"]
        }
    },
    "size": 5,
    "_source": ["title", "description"],
    "sort": {"modified": "asc"}
}
```

I would like to limit my description field response to 100 characters max. I'm new to ES. Could someone advice me on how to do it efficiently?

Comment: Isn't that something that's easily done in the frontend?

Comment: of course. but some of our descriptions are quite long example published papers. So I think it would be more efficient to do it in the backend ES service in my case

Comment: Oh I see. Lemme write an answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`highlighting`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-highlighting.html) to get just the relevant part of the matched `description`. It's got the `fragment_size` setting which is essentially the string concatenation you're after and, funny enough, defaults to 100.

```
POST long_desc/_doc
{"title":"UK House Price Index","keyword":"UK House Price Index","description":"APM automatically collects in-depth performance metrics and errors from inside your applications. Ingest logs UK House Price Index from popular data sources and easily visualize in preconfigured dashboards."}
```

```
GET long_desc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "UK House Price Index",
      "fields": [
        "title",
        "keyword",
        "description"
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 5,
  "_source": [
    "title"
  ],
  "sort": {
    "modified": "asc"
  },
  "highlight": {
    "pre_tags": "",
    "post_tags": "",
    "fragment_size": 1,
    "fields": {
      "description": {
        "fragment_size": 100,
        "number_of_fragments": 1,
        "fragmenter": "span"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

yielding

```
[
  {
    "_index":"long_desc",
    "_type":"_doc",
    "_id":"zSWAwnEBPAbzy1R_Uk-I",
    "_score":null,
    "_source":{
      "title":"UK House Price Index"
    },
    "highlight":{
      "description":[
        "Ingest logs UK House Price Index from popular data sources and easily visualize in preconfigured dashboards"
      ]
    }
    ...
  }
]
```

FYI `pre_` & `post_tags` default to `<em>` so your frontend doesn't really need to do any post processing to, uhm, highlight the matches. I chose empty strings to keep the `description` clean.